How to made my CUSE character device behaves like terminal device, when program opens it
I am writing something like user-space pseudo-terminal. When programs open /dev/tty or /dev/console, it complain about bad address or other strange error (no such device?). I need to made user-space or kernel-space behaves as like my character device be terminal device, in case of opening it.
